# Sharing authentication between parent and child web applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

We have two separate MVC 4 Web Applications that run as parts of the same website. The main (parent) project has authentication, and it works fine. Now that we've added the second project to the same site (one page that runs in a child frame), we can't figure out how to make it use the authorization that the user has undergone through the parent application.

Both use the same forms element in web.config:

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"  domain="..." protection="All" timeout="2880"/>
```

Do I need more than an [Authorize]-tag in the child project?

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ...

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }

    ...
}
```

Probably needless to say, the page is redirected to the logon-page if i try to access the child project's HomeController, even though a user is logged in in the parent project.

Both projects use the same machineKey.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the domain property is set to the parent domain:

```
<forms 
    loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" 
    name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"  
    domain="domain.com" 
    protection="All" 
    timeout="2880"
/>
```

Also make sure that you have set the same machine keys for both applications:

```
<machineKey validationKey="5C1E392DB9867A990FE0161B8BD07C1B165921DDAB21ADCC4C8F15D67EA2DECD7AEBB04409A411C69CB125EDEA3702B64DF17D47AD951461F444175BDF0277CF" decryptionKey="43CC900E97D496FC6C5C0C12FE005F9E846675C4BD45977BA5CEE852741ED3B6" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

This will ensure that a forms authentication cookie encrypted by the first application could be decrypted by the second. You could use the following website to generate strong machine keys.

(Link removed.  Is no longer valid)

Comment: They do use the same domain string, and they have the same machineKey element as well. The domain string is, however, like "domain.com" while the url the site is accessed through is like "sub1.sub2.domain.com". Does this make a difference as long as the strings match in parent and child web.configs?

Comment: No, if your websites are hosted on say `sub1.domain.com` and `sub2.domain.com` you should set the domain property to `domain="domain.com"`. This should work if you are not using any ASP.NET Session. This is only sharing forms authentication cookies, not sessions. If you rely on some session it won't work because the session is stored in the memory of the application by default. You will have to use a shared session provider such as SQL Server for example if you want to be able to share sessions between applications.

Comment: Yeah. We are just sharing form authentication cookies. So this SHOULD work. However, it doesn't. I can see that the cookie is created in Chrome, but not sure why the child project can't decrypt it.

Comment: Have you verified if the cookie is sent to the child domain when performing the request?

Comment: Thanks for your support Darin. It turned out that the other project had an error in setting the cookie.